# Displaying Image at different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

From my understanding of the Android support for multiple screens Support, layouts are scaled for screen density and size, whereas images are scaled for screen density.

This ensures that images will appear the same size on different density screens. To overcome possible scaling issues, it is recommended to provide different versions of the images with following the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four generalized densities.

However, if I have a screen that is simply to display a photo with some text underneath, and I want to take advantage of the extra screen size in some mobiles, and therefore display the photo at a larger size from the user's point of view than on the smaller screens, then what is the best way of doing this?

Also wrt displaying images, is it best to use wrap_content or dp – what is the advantage of one over the other ?

Thanks very much in advance

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your first question:
You probably need to specify a different drawable resource for every image you're going to do. Here is a link to the android developer's site that specifies methods of doing that. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Second:
If you specify the dp, you may cause some image distortion, however, if you use wrap_content, it may not be big enough. I would suggest for you to use wrap_content with different drawables for each screen density.

EDIT:

To find the actual size:
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); int width = display.getWidth(); int height = display.getHeight();

You're going to have to calculate it though based on the screen density.

And then just use mm or inches

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, but wrt the answer to the first question, that link only seems to descibe providing images for different screen densities so that the image displays at the same size on screens of different densities. I cannot see anywhere which suggests a solution to wanting an image to be displayed at a larger size on a larger screen (irrespective of density) ? Thanks

Comment: You could use mm or in to specify something based on the real size of the screen, although I wouldn't recommend it. You can find the real size of the screen using:

Comment: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

Comment: you have to calculate the inches based on the pixels and screen density.